# How do I introduce an assumption when defining a piecewise function?

Tags: function-construction, assumptions, piecewise

Define `m` as an integer. I want to specify a `Piecewise` function `f[x,n]` that takes value `n^3 x^2` except when `x` divides `m(n+1)`. At these values, I want `f[x,n]=1`.

I can't figure out how to do this because I can't work out how to include the assumption that `m` is an integer. I have

```
f[x_, n_] := 
  Piecewise[{
    {1, x ∈ Divisors[m (n + 1)]},
    {x^2  n^(1/2), x ∉ Divisors[m (n + 1)]}
  }, 
    Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers];
table =Table[f[x, n], {x, 1, 5}, {n, 0, 5}]
```

This doesn't work. How do I do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with `m` and the assumptions. Is `m` symbolic or numerical? If numerical, this is very simple: `f[x_, n_] := Piecewise[{{n^3 *x^2, Mod[x, m (m + 1)] != 0}, {1, Mod[x, m (m + 1)] == 0}}]` - but if `m` is symbolic, then this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hi @flinty. The `Mod` trick works if I eliminate the use of `m` entirely - it was just a dummy variable to stand for "integer multiples of `n+1`". Thank you. If you could tweak and post it as an answer, I'll tick it.

Comment: Maybe `ConditionalExpression` is what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `m` is just an integer multiple of `n+1`, you can do this with `Mod`:

```
f[x_, n_] := Piecewise[{{1, Mod[x, n+1] == 0}}, n^3 *x^2]

f[4, 3] (* returns 1 *)
f[5, 3] (* returns 675 == 3^3 * 5^2 *)

table = Table[f[x, n], {x, 1, 5}, {n, 0, 5}]
(* returns: {{1, 1, 8, 27, 64, 125}, {1, 1, 32, 108, 256, 500}, {1, 9, 1, 243, 
  576, 1125}, {1, 1, 128, 1, 1024, 2000}, {1, 25, 200, 675, 1, 3125}} *)
```